# get class hierarchy of enum field

Tags: c#, .net, class, enums

i have class like this

```
public class SomeClass {
    public enum Fields {
        field1,
        field2
    }
    //... another fields
}
```

and pass filed in some function

```
public void Do(Enum field) {
    string name = DontKnowHow(field);
}
```

and i want that name == "SomeClass" or contain it.
is it possible?

Comment: Is there a reason for declaring the enum inside the class? Why not simply hold an instance of your `Fields` enum inside `SomeClass`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need it that way?

Comment: Why is it not `public void Do(SomeClass.Fileds field) {...`. Btw is it `Fileds` or `Fields`?

Comment: there are several classes with Fields property and i want pass params in Do(Enum field) from any class.
Yes, Fields but not Fileds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it sounds like you're doing something wrong, answer you're expecting is here.

```
string name = field.GetType().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Note: If enum provided is not a nested type, you'll get `NullReferenceException` as `DeclaringType` will be null.